# How call UINavigationControllerDelegate delegate method for rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using below delegate method to show animation in my app.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
            animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController,
            to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
```

But, above method is not getting call for rootViewController of navigationController.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What is FromVC and toVC. Can you explain here? From what view to what view you want to navigate?

Comment: I am navigating from my loginVC/RegisterVC to myOneTimeVC. I am presenting MyOneTimeVC on LoginVC/RegisterVC. I want navigation transition called for MyOneTimeVC

Comment: Where are you implementing this method?  Are you properly setting the delegate for the UINavigationController?  How are you displaying MyOneTimeVC?

Comment: @ChrisAllwein I am presenting MyOnetimeVC. I am implementing this method in UINavigationControllerDelegate extension.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're referring to is called to set up the transition animation.  However, the rootViewController is added to the navigationController without any animation since there is no previous view controller to transition from.  As a result, the delegate method is not invoked.

This is true even if you don't use the convenience initializer that specifies the rootViewController and instead push the rootViewController manually, specifying `true` for the `animated:` parameter.  You'll notice that even in this case, the navigationController pushes the rootViewController without animation (as evidenced from the `navigationController(:,willShow:,animated:)` call having the `animated` parameter set to `false`.

AFAIK, it is not possible to transition-animate the rootViewController.

An alternative solution might be to implement `navigationController(:, willShow:, animated:)`, do a check to see if `self.viewControllers.first == viewController` and then manually animate the `viewController.view`.